# Making custom waypoints by using a .getJSON for google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to have a function for calculating routes for google maps be dynamically changed based on data retrieved from a .getJSON.  I have tried including the bulk of the function calcRoute() under a .done function, but I am receiving an error in property waypoints in the javascript console.  I am at a loss as what to do, because when I don't include the bulk of the function under the .done, the array remains blank (asynchronous call with the .getJSON.  Here is the code to give you a better idea:

```
    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        var waypts = [];
        var data = $.getJSON("/westcoast_map.php", {
            westcoast_id: $('.opener').data('westcoast_id')
        }, function(json) {
            return json[1];
        });

        data.done(function(theData) {
            waypts = theData[1];
            console.log(waypts); //this spits out the array in the proper format, i.e. {location:city, state, stopover:true},...etc...

            var request = {
                origin: start,
                destination: end,
                waypoints: waypts,
                optimizeWaypoints: true,
                travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            };

            directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                    var route = response.routes[0];
                    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
                    summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
                    // For each route, display summary information.
                    for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                        var routeSegment = i + 1;
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    }
```

Comment: i'm not exactly sure what your problem is, what does not work if you place the callback you have currently in the `.done()` part at the place where you currently have `function(json) { return json[1]; }?

Comment: The array will stay empty when the rest of the code runs because it is asynchronous;  could you give me an example in code of what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

i'm still not sure what you problem is, because the code pared you show, should at least work from the logical part. but there are parts where it is not clear what you try to achive:

```
    var data = $.getJSON("/westcoast_map.php", {
        westcoast_id: $('.opener').data('westcoast_id')
    }, function(json) {
        return json[1];
    });
```

if you expect here that `data`  will become `json[1]`, then your assumption is wrong.
`$.getJSON` returns always **jQuery XHR**. the callback function will be called later when the browser received the data.

Here a little example to understand how async works:
the callback functions 1 and 2 are called when the client gets the response for the request, but not before the original script was completely executed, so `doSomethingElse()` will be always called before the callback function 1 and 2 are executed.
the order in which callback function 1 and 2 are executed depends on which response arrives first.

```
var test = [];
preparesSomeStuff();

$.getJSON("someurl1",{},function() {
   //Callback Function 1

});

doSomething();

$.getJSON("someurl2",{},function() {
   //Callback Function 2
});


doSomethingElse();
//<<END OF SCRIPT>>
```

if you don't want to have your whole code inside of the callback function (e.g. because of readability) you could do it the following way:

```
function calcRoute() {
    var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
    var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
    var waypts = [];
    $.getJSON("/westcoast_map.php", {
        westcoast_id: $('.opener').data('westcoast_id')
    }, function(theData) {
        calcualteRoute(theData[1], start, end);
    });

    //if you place code here it will be executed before displayResult will be called because getJSON is async
}


function calcualteRoute(waypts, start, end) {
    console.log(waypts); //this spits out the array in the proper format, i.e. {location:city, state, stopover:true},...etc...

    var request = {
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        waypoints: waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };

    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            displayResult(response,status);
        }
    });

    //if you place some code here it will be executed BEFORE displayResult will be called, because 
    //directionsService.route is async

}

function displayResult(response, status) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    var route = response.routes[0];
    var summaryPanel = document.getElementById('directions_panel');
    summaryPanel.innerHTML = '';
    // For each route, display summary information.
    for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
        var routeSegment = i + 1;
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += '<b>Route Segment: ' + routeSegment + '</b><br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + ' to ';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + '<br>';
        summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + '<br><br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I make sure that calculateRoute(waypts) is called?  I am calling calcRoute() on click.

Comment: @user1072337 sorry was a mistake. the first callback should have been `calcualteRoute` ... fixed my post

Comment: This is still not performing anything unfortunately...nothing happens upon the button click

Comment: I'm getting this error in the console: Error: Invalid value for property <origin>: [object HTMLSelectElement]

Comment: The origin, and end, are being fed by a select id.

Comment: forgot to passe them to the function (`, start, end` where missing)